# Cannot checkout project from SVN to USB drive

Tags: eclipse, svn, assembla, svn-checkout

I'm trying to checkout a project from an SVN repo (@assembla), and I'm getting wierd errors that all state the connection has been reset by the remote host...

The wierd thing is that I only get these errors when trying to checkout into my USB drive - when trying to checkout into my HD I'm not getting any errors...

I've tried checking out via Tortoise SVN, Eclipse's Subclibse and Subversive and all have the same problem.

Some things I've noticed:

- The error always occurs when it's trying to check out the main images folder, though not always on the same file in that folder.
- I was able to check out smaller folders (I was even able to check out the problematic folder on it's own).
- It seems the error occurs when about 1MB of data has been transferred, so that might explain the previous bullet.
- I also noticed that checking out into my HD was a lot faster, so perhaps assembla is terminating the transactions because they're taking too long?

Comment: It sounds like a problem copying files to your USB drive, you could  checkout to your harddrive, then copy that entire folder to your usb drive, then you have it there and can work from it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm gonna work through Eclipse, and for it to recognize and associate the project with the repository, I have to import it via the eclipse plugins (at least I think that's the case)...